# What specific threats could a haunted house contain?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

I‘m currently working on an haunted house scenario and need some threats to the characters to heighten the tension.

The setting:

- It is a Hunter the Vigil Game
- Set in 2020 in Germany (no Corona)

The House:

- It is a three storied building with about 15 rooms.
- In this story, the house itself is the antagonist/monster
- The house contains a mysterious machine that is no longer working. The purpose of the machine is not important to the story (I don’t even know it myself). But the house wants the 2 characters to fix it. The problem with that is, that some parts for the repair would need to be made, out of one of the characters bones.
- The characters are not able to leave the house. But I don’t know how the house could try to force them to do want it wants.

Ideally each room room should have some sort of physical thread to the characters, that is not lethal but threatening. Threads I already have:

- The gas stove will leek some gas that the house can ignite when the characters enter the kitchen. Not enough for a huge explosion but definitively threatening. Causing some burns.
- A chandelier will swing down from the ceiling trying to hit a character.
- Some parts of the floor a made of metal and can give the characters electric shocks.
- Doors can suddenly slam shut hitting someone who walks through. (I don’t really like this one because it disincentivizes moving through the house to find a method of escape.)

What other threats could I use?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG.SE, it looks like you're asking for an opinion on what the threats could be, but that makes selecting an objectively correct answer difficult. Because of that this specific question may not be suitable for this site, but we welcome more questions form you, because you clearly put a lot of effort into this!

Comment: If you're looking for a good place to ask, we have a list of resources (forums) [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). I've also upvoted your question, so you should also have access to our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat) :D